# Embedded questions grammar

Tags: embedded-clauses

There are some sentences from https://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/courses/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/410-embedded-questions2.htm

I believe just the first sentence is correct, but the source says the third one is correct.

- I wonder how much will it cost to take a taxi home after the annual office   party
- I've never eaten at this restaurant. Can you tell me what should I order?
- I've never eaten this before. Do you know what is in it?

Also, I just was wondering why this is considered to be incorrect:

- Does anyone know why was today's meeting postponed until next week?

Comment: You have three list items followed by a block quote. That makes four sentences. Why is the fourth one presented differently than the other three? Also, I would consider only the third list item to be grammatical and idiomatic. (It is, however, at least three sentences, not just one. I can't tell if the fourth sentence is supposed to be part of it or not.) The first list item is at least unidiomatic, the second is definitely ungrammatical, and the block quote is at least unidiomatic.

Comment: ive edited to match the source

Comment: Embedded questions do not have subject-auxiliary inversion, so only your third example is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Questions in English have both a question word (what, how, etc.) and swap the subject and verb. In "What is it" the subject (it) has been moved after the verb (is). Only "is" and auxiliary verbs are swapped. "What will you see". The subject (you) moves after the auxiliary (will).  If a regular verb in a simple tense is used, then "Do" is needed (What do you want)

When a question is embedded the swap is not done: "Tell me what it is.", "Tell me what you will see", or "Tell me what you want".

All three examples have embedded questions

"I wonder how much will it cost"  Has an incorrect swapping of will and it.

"tell me what should I order" incorrectly swaps should and I

"Do you know what is in it" is a little different.

The statement could be "Meat is in it".  The question is a subject question as the missing information (Meat) is the subject.  Subject questions don't swap the subject and verb, you ask "What is in it?".  Compare the meaning of that question with "What is it in?", which does swap the verb.

So in the last example there is no swapping to undo, so the embedded question is the same as the regular question. There is no error in the third example.

The fourth example is similar. To form an embedded question you don't swap the subject and verb. The subject is "today's meeting" and the verb is "was" so it should be

"Does anyone know why today's meeting was postponed until next week?"

Comment: "Questions in English have both a question word (what, how, etc.) and swap the subject and verb." <-- Are you being serious? (See what I did there?)

Comment: "Only "is" and auxiliary verbs are swapped" <-- Aherm?

Comment: How about *am, are, was, were*?

Comment: Hi, no I got diverted here by following DS's link to this question. I'm on a mission to show him that *be* is always an auxiliary regardless of whether there's a following verb, etymological fallacies not withstanding. anyhow your posts are normally very accurate and clawer, so I thought you might appreciate the heads ups.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by James K is quite correct, except that "subject questions" and "object questions" are not in my view a useful set of categories, as is described in an answer to [this deleted question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222786/could-you-explain-if-given-questions-are-subject-or-object-questions).

The examples:

> - I wonder how much will it cost?
> - Can you tell me what should I order?

both do inversion (swapping) where it is not needed, or indeed allowed by proper grammer, because the questions are embedded in larger statements. Note that if the questions are asked separately, without being embedded, inversion is not only permitted, but required. Using the same examples  but without embedding:

> - How much will it cost?
> - What should I order?

are correct and natural.

Note that the incorrect examples will still be understood by most fluent speakers, and even fluent speakers get this wrong sometimes. So one may hear or read embedded questions that improperly apply inversion.

Comment: How would you explain to a user on this site why there is no inversion in "Who humiliated Donald?" but there is in "Who did Donald humiliate?" Careful, mind!

Comment: And how would you explain the following data to a student: *Who shot JR?*, *Who did JR shoot?*,    *Who is she?*, *Was John sad?* but not *Who did shot JR?*, *Who JR shot?*, *Who she is?*, *Who does she be?*, *Did John be sad?* Pretty impossible if you don't explain both that subject questions don't have SAI and that BE is (always) an auxiliary verb! I'd love to  watch you try! ;-)